# how to get the ID for a status update page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that has lots of users that would like to see their FB status updates on their particular page.
I assume I need to use the Graph API and I have that working as far as getting something back from graph.facebook.com/username.

But not sure how to get the status updates. It appears that I need the ID for the status messages. How do I retrieve this ID for a particular user?

If I do a https://graph.facebook.com/someonespage/feed?access_token=

I see this in the return but it doesn't have the pageID:

```
    'type' => 'status',
   'created_time' => '2011-11-16T21:44:32+0000',
   'updated_time' => '2011-11-16T21:44:32+0000',
   'comments' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'count' => 0,
```

Or is this not the way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /feed connection is analogous to the contents of the user's wall, the 'statuses' connection is only the status updates made by that user - a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/statuses?access_token=...` should return their statuses when you have the read_stream permission

The uid will work in place of USERNAME above, and is probably a better way to implement your app for consistency reasons, but username works ok too

Comment: thanks Igy, so when i tried https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/statuses?access_token= i got the following error
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
I took feed (that worked) and replaced it with statuses
is that the read_stream permission? how do i get that?
Thanks alot for your help

Comment: so from a little more research i need user_status permission. But it looks like i can not use my access token. is that correct. 
Does this mean each time my cron wants to get this users status the user has to login? I seem to be misisng part of the flow needed

Comment: Why not just get an offline_access token which won't expire with the session (though will if the password is changed and other various other cases)

Comment: Igy, so i am now asking for offline_access during the auth but not sure how to us it? how to i get the offline_access token?

Comment: i think i found how to get the offline_access token. So the way to use  is to save that token in a DB? thanks again for you help

Comment: Yep; storing the offline_access token seems like the best solution for what you're trying to do here - just be aware that it may expire eventually, especially if the user changes their password, uninstalls the app, etc

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you user activity/posts. Login not required. This will not include status updates.

https://graph.facebook.com/UserNameOrUserID/feed?access_token=AccessToken

The following will give you user's status updates only but login is required. How to get user status updates without having to login to facebook. My status updates are all public.

https://graph.facebook.com/UserNameOrUserID/statuses?access_token=UserAccessToken

Comment: I think you should pasted your code in, since it's not too long. That would prevent your answer being useless if both links break.